# ClassNotFoundException with Spring Boot and ibm JDBC driver

Tags: java, spring, maven, jdbc, spring-boot

I'm trying to set up a spring-boot application to connect to a DB2 database on an IBM i machine.  I've added a maven dependency to an IBM jdbc driver `com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver` and added `spring.datasource.driver-class-name="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver"` to the application.properties file.

When I run the application, I get an error `Cannot load driver class: "com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver`.  The error happens at the `ClassUtils.forName` line below in the DataSourceProperties class from spring-boot in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc

```
private boolean driverClassIsLoadable() {
    try {
        ClassUtils.forName(this.driverClassName, null); <----- Exception happens here.  
        return true;
    }
    catch (UnsupportedClassVersionError ex) {
        // Driver library has been compiled with a later JDK, propagate error
        throw ex;
    }
    catch (Throwable ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

this.driverClassName equals "com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver".  Interestingly, in my main method, I can call the same function with the same driverClassName and get no exception.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MinimumExampleApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, LinkageError {
    ClassUtils.forName("com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver", null); <---- No exception here?
    SpringApplication.run(MinimumExampleApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

My question is why is spring-boot unable to find the driver when I can find the driver if I load it myself?

Full Program

`MinimumExample.java`

```
package org.mystuff.annual.meeting.signup;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.util.ClassUtils;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MinimumExampleApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException,    LinkageError {
    ClassUtils.forName("com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver", null);
    SpringApplication.run(MinimumExampleApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

`application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver"
spring.datasource.url="jdbc:db2://myserver/myDb"
spring.datasource.dbcp2.initial-size=2
spring.datasource.dbcp2.max-total=5
```

`pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.mystuff</groupId>
    <artifactId>annual-meeting-signup</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>minimum-example</name>
    <description>Playing with data repository</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.mystuff</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.as400</groupId>
            <artifactId>jt400</artifactId>
            <version>8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: What about the other class, in which you are getting the exception? Is that class annotated with any of Spring annotations? In other words, is it spring  bean?

Comment: The other class is DataSourceProperties within spring-boot so it is library code.  It gets called when configuring the dataSource as far as I can tell.

Comment: I suspect it's the quotes around the property values in `application.properties` that's causing the problem. What happens if you remove them?

Comment: Well, you are right :P.  Silly newb error but I thank you.  If you post as an answer, i'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Andy Wilkinson mentioned, the problem was caused by the quotes in my application.properties file.  I had it configured like this

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver"
spring.datasource.url="jdbc:db2://myserver/myDb"
spring.datasource.dbcp2.initial-size=2
spring.datasource.dbcp2.max-total=5
```

If I change to the below it works

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:db2://myserver/myDb
spring.datasource.dbcp2.initial-size=2
spring.datasource.dbcp2.max-total=5
```